# Found average of one variable per value of other variable, but how to use the result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to extract some meaning from a dataset of age, weight, and exercise time.

I was able to find the average weight for each age, but now I don't now what to do with that data because it is not a column or an array. I can I turn this into something useful if I want to plot it or use it in a function.

```
person_data_url = 'url'
df = pd.read_csv(persons_data_url, ...)

avg = df.groupby('age')['weight'].aggregate(np.mean)
```

looks like this

```
age
18    148.000000
19    125.086957
20    161.000000
21    171.500000
22    119.368421
23    139.285714
24    149.411765
25    167.789474
26    186.400000
27    161.500000
```

[image]

Is it possible to make a plot or graph where each average weight was on the y-axis and the age on the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib` and `reset_index()` on your calculated dataframe and then just simply plot the columns vs one another:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': np.random.randint(18,27,size=100),
    'weight': np.random.randint(120,240,size=100)
})

avg = df.groupby('age').agg('mean').reset_index()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(avg['age'], avg['weight'])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Weight')
plt.title('Weight vs Age')
plt.show()
```